# Passing temporary objects by reference

Tags: c++, arguments, pass-by-reference, temporary-objects

I have two classes:
Circle and Dot

Class Circle contains a Dot, and Dot contains an int. Circle has a getDot() function, and Dot has a lessThan(Dot& ) function.

I want to sort an array of Circles, elems[], by the int values inside Dot. If I have a Circle circ that I want to compare to some value in the array, I essentially need a line that does the following:

```
elems[0].getDot().lessThan(circ.getDot())
```

But it won't compile... I can fix the issue by having a temporary

```
Dot dt = circ.getDot()
```

and passing

```
elems[0].getDot().lessThan(dt)
```

but this seems like unnecessary copying. Is there a more efficient way to solve this?

Unfortunately, I am limited to using lessThan(dot&) for comparison, but I can modify the contents of it.

The compiler error is:
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Dot&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Dot’             cout<

Comment: Why does it take a _non_ const reference though?

Comment: if the argument to lessThan is a reference, you're not copying it.  Furthermore, the initial construction/assignment will typically be elided.  The net effect should be identical to using a temporary (except that `dt` is explicitly in scope)

Comment: Can you change the function to take `Dot const&` instead?

Comment: I see, I didn't know the difference between const and non-const references. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Dot
{
    Dot(int i) : value_(i) {}
    bool lessThan(Dot const& other) const
    {
        return value_ < other.value_;
    }

    int value_;
};

struct Circle
{
    Circle(Dot dot = Dot(0))
    : dot_(dot)
    {
    }

    const Dot& getDot() const { return dot_; }

    Dot dot_;
};


void sortCircles(std::vector<Circle>& circles)
{
    auto order = [](Circle const& l, Circle const& r)
    {
        return l.getDot().lessThan(r.getDot());
    };
    std::sort(circles.begin(), circles.end(), order);
}
```

Comment: @Fib011 the trick is usually in the provision of const accessor methods on your objects.